# Integer.parseInt: 0xff80CBC4 is an invalid int

Tags: java, integer, hex, parseint

Can somebody please explain why the second and the third of the following statements fail?

```
Integer myColor = 0xff80CBC4 //works

Integer.parseInt("0xff80CBC4".substring(2), 16) //does not work
Integer.decode("0xff80CBC4") //does not work
```

When run, the following exception is thrown:

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "ff80CBC4"`

If you use `00` instead of `ff` at the start of `ff80CBC4`, it works. Why does it fail with `ff`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Please note that there is no such thing as "it does not work".  Exceptions are issued.  ***Mention them.***</sup>

`Integer.parseInt()` and `Integer.decode()` fail because the literal 0xff80CBC4  that you are trying to parse is too large for a signed integer to represent it.  (Read-up on [two's complement notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to find out why.)

The truth is that it could have been interpreted as a negative integer, but these functions do not know that, so they try to parse it as a positive integer.

Try this:

```
    String s = "0xff80CBC4";
    int a = Integer.parseInt( s.substring( 2, 4 ), 16 );
    int r = Integer.parseInt( s.substring( 4, 6 ), 16 );
    int g = Integer.parseInt( s.substring( 6, 8 ), 16 );
    int b = Integer.parseInt( s.substring( 8, 10 ), 16 );
    int argb = a << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
    System.out.printf( "%2x %2x %2x %2x %8x\n", a, r, g, b, argb );
```

It prints:

```
ff 80 cb c4 ff80cbc4
```

Comment: The value represents an ARGB color for use with android. How do I parse the value correctly? (So that I get `-8336444`. It has to be an integer)

Comment: @Campbell I amended my answer with a solution that does not involve parsing a long.

Comment: @DontPanic I debugged through it and you are right, so I changed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The string defines a number that is too large for the Integer object. You can use Long for example.

```
    Long a = Long.parseLong("0xff80CBC4".substring(2), 16);
    System.out.println(a); //4286630852
    Integer max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(max); //2147483647
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer.decode() need positive value, but NumberFormatException is thrown not by this reason.

when you pass "0xff80CBC4" to Integer.decode(), the "0x" is discarded, so the value is ff80CBC4 and it is too large for Integer.

```
// Handle radix specifier, if present
        if (nm.startsWith("0x", index) || nm.startsWith("0X", index)) {
            index += 2;
            radix = 16;
        }
```

But if you pass "0xff80CBC4" to Long.decode() - everithing will be ok.

Comment: But I need it to overflow as an integer, because thats the format that android uses for color. How would I do that?